# Magento2 Object Manager Issue in MTF test run windows

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, testing, unit-tests, ftf

I am learning on how to use MTF in my test module. I am trying to run generator using command

```
php generate.php
```

But I am getting following error -

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Mtf\ObjectManagerFactory' not found
```

I am following the following link

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_quickstart/mtf_quickstart_environment.html

Also there was an error which was coming before due to line in bootstrap.php-

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

So I gave path to `autoload.php` assuming it was path to the `autoload.php` located in vendor folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by following this link -

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_installation.html#mtf_install_check

All which was needed was to run `composer install` at location

`cd <magento2_root_dir>/dev/tests/functional/`